# Passing parameters to function inside object

Tags: javascript

I first obtain an element:

```
var i=document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset");
```

Then I create a new object:

```
var a=new Fieldset(i[0]);
```

The function prototype is this:

```
slideDown: function() {  
    alert("here");  
}
```

The constructor function is this:

```
function Fieldset(fieldset){  
    this.fieldset=fieldset;
    this.fieldset.addEventListener("click",this.slideDown(this.fieldset),false);  
};
```

The problem is that the `slideDown` function is called immediately when the new object is created and the listener is not attached to the element.

I've done the code with and without the `this` in front of fieldset in the constructor for the listener to no avail. I just don't know where I'm fumbling this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in this expression

```
this.fieldset.addEventListener("click",this.slideDown(this.fieldset),false);
```

`slideDown()` is called **before** `addEventListener()` since arguments are evaluated before the function is called.

You probably mean to pass a function object as second argument rather than passing a value returned by `slideDown()` (which doesn't return anything anyway). You can construct such a function object this way:

```
function Fieldset(fieldset){
  this.fieldset=fieldset;
  var self = this; // stash "this" for use inside listener below.
  var listener = function() {
    self.slideDown(fieldset);
  };
  this.fieldset.addEventListener("click", listener, false);
};
```

We use variable `self` to store the value of `this`. Note that `this` is not available inside `listener` anymore.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I had forgotten that. I'm not the js guy here but was called into action.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your event handler in an anonymous function:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F7LYn/)

```
var i=document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset");

var a=new Fieldset(i[0]);

function Fieldset(fieldset){
    this.fieldset=fieldset;
    this.slideDown =  function() {
        alert("here");
         }
        var f = this;
        this.fieldset.addEventListener("click", function() {
            f.slideDown(f.fieldset)
        },false);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function (el, h) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function () {h(el);}, false);
})(this.fieldset, this.slideDown);
```